# Converting an arbitrary seed into a float between 0 and 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, cryptography, random-seed

I want to be able to change any string containing any utf-8 into a random number between 0 and 1.

I can convert any seed that is a number with the following:

`Math.abs(Math.sin(seed));`

From this I'm able to generate a pseudo seeded `Math.random()`-like number.

So it's converting a string into a number. I looked into using crypto and found that making a digest of the string works but is incredibly slow, and is a bit overkill.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Start with `crypto.randomBytes()`.

Comment: Are you aware that `Math.sin()` will give you a distribution skewed towards 1? (Or is that intentional?)

Comment: @duskwuff in what way is that distribution skewed towards 1?

Comment: @BrandonSmith The derivative of sin(x) is at a maximum when sin(x) is close to zero, and minimum when it's close to ±1; that means it ends up spending less "time" close to zero.

Comment: @duskwuff Very interesting. Can you suggest an alternative I can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using String.prototype.charCodeAt() you can generate an integer representation:

```
function stringToSeed(str){
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    values.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  // concatenatte and coerce to integer 
  return values.join('') + 0;
}

var seed = stringToSeed(string);
```

You can then pass this seed to sin as you were before.

The thought behind concatenation instead of simply adding the values is to ensure that order is taken into account for randomness, otherwise "AB" and "BA" would produce the same value, for example.